# Connecting to Java Server via external IP

Tags: java, connection, ip

I have developed an application to transmit coordinates of one device to another and the distance between each is calculated.  I wrote a java server and had been connecting both devices locally.  However, now I want to test this over greater distances, in order to do so I need to connect one device to the external ip and use 3g in order to carry the device to over 500m.

I thought it might just have been a case of finding my external ip and putting that in where I had my local ip, however, there is no connection..I am still connecting the other device locally which is fine as there is no 3g on it anyway.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions as to what I need to do in this regard?

Thanks in advance,
Gary

Comment: who's doing the connection? remember that mobile devices (e.g. smartphones) are pretty much ALWAYS behind a NAT gateway/firewall, so if you're trying to reach out to the phone from your desktop, you can't. And your home pc is almost always natted by your router as well.

Comment: I would add on to Marc's comment that unless you have a static IP assigned to you by your ISP, you are probably never going to be able to connect back to your local machine.

Comment: Is there a port open on the devices in question?

Comment: @MarcB they are both smart phones and both are connecting to the server which is on the desktop.

Comment: @MattN unfortunately the ip isn't static, so does that definitely rule it out?

Comment: @handuel I'm unsure as to what you mean when you ask is there a port open on the devices, I'm new to this I'm afraid.  I have however forwarded ports (5353, 3689 - for TCP and UDP I've read) & I've forwarded my defined port of 1980.  I've also added a rule to the advanced firewall settings to allow 1980..

Comment: you'd have to make sure the phones are connecting to your external ip. e.g. the IP you get from your isp that gets set in your router. e.g. if the phones are tryign to connect to 192.168.10.2, they'll never make it, because that's a private non-routeable IP address.

Comment: @Marc B, I had them both connecting to the local ip while developing, now to test over further distance I went to whatsmyip.com to get my external  one, to have one connect to that & the other continues to connect locally, or do both have to connect to the external ip?

Comment: if they're going over a non-local connection (e.g. you're on 3g data), then yes, they'll have to use the external IP that you get, because they won't be going over YOUR network anymore. Might be the same device, but the network path taken by wifi, usb tether, etc.. is utterly different than the network path taken by 3g.

Comment: So at the mo I have one local & one external, if I set them that they're both connecting external it should work? I need to get a sim pack for the second device in order to enable 3g

Comment: In that case there is, having an open port and a forwarded port means the same thing.

Comment: @handuel - Any thoughts?